# Ansible - Search regex string in file

Tags: regex, string, ansible

I need to search regex string in a file, when this is fulfilled I want a message back. I have problems searching for this string.

Any ideas to solve this?

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  name: check PermitRootLogin
  shell: "sudo cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config"
  register: check_ssh
- debug:
        msg: 'This server is ok'
   when: check_ssh.splitlines()|select('match', '^PermitRootLogin\s*no\s*')|list
```

thanks for your time and support

Comment: What's the pattern you want to match?

Comment: "PermitRootLogin no"

it doesn't matter how many spaces you have between both words

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one :

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  name: check PermitRootLogin
  shell: "sudo cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config"
  register: check_ssh
- debug:
        msg: 'This server is ok'
  when: check_ssh.stdout is match("^PermitRootLogin.*no.*")
```